# how to find and remove multiple documents from mongo with one query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

java mongo driver has a findAndRemove method which finds some documents specified by a query and removes them.
My problem is how to find and remove specified (forexample 100) number of documents from a collection.
That would be something like

```
DBObject objects= db.getCollection("someCollection").findAndRemove( 100) ;
```

where objects is a list of deleted objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findAndRemove` is implemented via `findAndModify`, which in turn has the following limitation:

> command can be used to atomically modify a document (at most one) and
>   return it

(from [`findAndModify` documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command))

Comment: thanx , So youre saying there is no way?!

Comment: The official documentation says so.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what your after is to remove documents in bulk, something like

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("age", 25);
db.getCollection("someCollection").remove(query);
```

This is joews's answer to a similar question that I had here 
[Use MongoDB db.collection.remove(query) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134261/use-mongodb-db-collection-removequery-in-java/20134330?noredirect=1#20134330)